# Facing Buildozer error stating command failed

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, android-sdk-tools, buildozer, kivymd

I am using buildozer for building a kivymd app for android. I am using a MAC environment.
Facing below error trying to build an apk using buildozer.
buildozer -v android debug

> ```
> # Apache ANT found at /Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
> # Android SDK found at /Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
> # Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19c
> # Android NDK found at /Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
> # Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary
> # Run '/Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager
> ```
>
> --sdk_root=/Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk platform-tools'
> # Cwd /Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

```
> # Command failed: /Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager
> --sdk_root=/Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk platform-tools
> # ENVIRONMENT:
> #     USER = 'username'
> #     TERMINAL_EMULATOR = 'JetBrains-JediTerm'
> #     HOME = '/Users/username'
> #     COMMAND_MODE = 'unix2003'
> #     LOGIN_SHELL = '1'
> #     XPC_SERVICE_NAME = '0'
> #     LOGNAME = 'username'
> #     TMPDIR = '/var/folders/mg/pd47f87s21d89_00cyg72yhh0000gn/T/'
> #     SHELL = '/bin/zsh'
> #     __INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__ = ('/Users/username/Library/Application ' 
> 'Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/terminal/history/history-1')
> #     SECURITYSESSIONID = '186a9'
> #     XPC_FLAGS = '0x0'
> #     LaunchInstanceID = 'CF4B72E0-9C51-4676-832F-82CD1E647797'
> #     LC_CTYPE = 'UTF-8'
> #     __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F5:0x0:0x0'
> #     __CFBundleIdentifier = 'com.jetbrains.pycharm'
> #     PATH = '/Users/username/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/100daysofcode/venv/bin:/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/username/Developer/flutter/bin:/Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/bin'
> #     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
> #     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.rqXq6flgNC/Listeners'
> #     SHLVL = '1'
> #     PWD = '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/100daysofcode/FinanceTracker_Deploy'
> #     OLDPWD = '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/100daysofcode'
> #     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/100daysofcode/venv'
> #     PS1 = '(venv) %n@%m %1~ %# '
> #     _ = '/Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/bin/buildozer'
> # 
> # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
> # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
> # Please read the full log, and search for it before
> # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
> # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: You don't have java installed properly?